# SUMIFS excluding two criteria

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to do SUMIFS with two criteria I want to exclude.
I want to count the amount of fruit sold by all, excluding cherries sold by James.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Qty | Product | Salesperson |
| 5 | Apples | James |
| 10 | Apples | Jack |
| 15 | Apples | Ben |
| 20 | Bananas | Ben |
| 15 | Bananas | Jack |
| 10 | Cherries | James |
| 5 | Grapes | Ben |
| 10 | Grapes | James |
| 15 | Cherries | Jack |
| 20 | Melons | Ben |

I've tried

=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,AND(B:B"<>Cherries",C:C"<> James"))

but got an error.

=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<>Cherries",C:C,"<>James")

Also does not work as it doesn't count and Cherries or anything sold by James.

From the data above I would expect 115 as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subtract the part from the whole:

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"Cherries",C:C,"James")
```

[image]